# How to use ViewLocation with multiple views for the same type with ReactiveUI?

Tags: c#, autofac, reactiveui, avaloniaui

I am using [ViewLocation](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/view-location/) feature of ReactiveUI with splat autofac for autowiring views with view models. Is it possible to have multiple views for the same type, and choose which one to use based on some parameter?

Here is a simple example of what I would like to do:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
}
```

View #1 for Person class:

```
<UserControl
    ...namespaces...>
    <TextBox Name="NameTextBox"/>
</UserControl>
```

and code behind

```
public partial class PersonNameView : ReactiveUserControl<Person>
{
    public PersonNameView()
    {
        this.WhenActivated(disposables => {
            this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Name, v => v.NameTextBox.Text).DisposeWith(disposables);
        });
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

View #2 for Person class:

```
<UserControl
    ...namespaces...>
    <TextBox Name="AgeTextBox"/>
</UserControl>
```

and code behind

```
public partial class PersonAgeView : ReactiveUserControl<Person>
{
    public PersonAgeView()
    {
        this.WhenActivated(disposables => {
            this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Age, v => v.AgeTextBox.Text).DisposeWith(disposables);
        });
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Somewhere In the main view there would be a collection of Persons:

```
<!--other code-->
<ItemsControl Name=PersonItemsControl/>
```

and in code behind

```
public partial class MainView : ReactiveUserControl<MainViewModel>
{
    public MainView()
    {
        //other code
        this.WhenActivated(disposables => {
            this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Persons, v => v.PersonItemsControl.ItemsSource).DisposeWith(disposables);
        });
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Both Views are registered with autofac:

```
builder.RegisterType<PersonNameView>().As<IViewFor<Person>>().InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<PersonAgeView>().As<IViewFor<Person>>().InstancePerDependency();
```

If my observation is correct if multiple views are registered for the same type, the last registered view is chosen (`PersonAgeView` in this case). But is there a way to choose which one is used?

Keep in mind this is very simplified example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible as Lukasz suggested with contracts (his answer led to this solution). I'm not sure if it is possible with **autofac** or other DI implementations for ReactiveUI because I found no way to register contract. So i switched to native splat DI. With splat you have two options.

#1 when manually registering views there is a contract parameter

```
Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => new PersonNameView(), typeof(IViewFor<Person>));
Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => new PersonAgeView(), typeof(IViewFor<Person>), contract: "age");
```

#2 when using `Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterViewsForViewModels(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());` to automatically register views, you can use attribute **[ViewContract](https://www.reactiveui.net/api/reactiveui/viewcontractattribute/)** to decorate view.

```
[ViewContract("age")]
public partial class PersonAgeView : ReactiveUserControl<Person>
{
    public PersonAgeView()
    {
        this.WhenActivated(disposables => {
            this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Age, v => v.AgeTextBox.Text).DisposeWith(disposables);
        });
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

For some reason you cannot use **ViewContract** attribute when manually registering views so be mindful of that.

To choose which registration to use, you have to use **[ViewModelViewHost](https://www.reactiveui.net/api/reactiveui/viewmodelviewhost/)** inside your view and provide contract info.

namespace:

```
xmlns:reactive="using:Avalonia.ReactiveUI"
```

view:

```
<!--other code-->
<ItemsControl
    Name="PersonItemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <reactive:ViewModelViewHost
                ViewModel="{Binding .}"
                ViewContract="age"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting topic. I checked a source code of the [ViewModelViewHost](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/c07422894d6aa759e83a1ea63a64accf7247397f/src/ReactiveUI.Wpf/Common/ViewModelViewHost.cs#L151) control, and it has properties: `ViewContract` and `ViewContractObservable`. It looks like you can use one of them to allow resolving views using contracts. In such case, during registration, you will need to register the view with contract info.

Comment: I think you are on the right track, with more digging I found out that you can use `ViewContractAttribute` to decorate `IViewFor<>` class. Now I know how to differentiate multiple views for the same ViewModel, but I still don't understand how to choose which one to use.

Comment: You should use a `ViewModelViewHost` control in places when you put your user controls which implement `IViewFor<>` and bind `ViewContract` on `ViewModelViewHost.`

Comment: I figured it out in the meantime, it is as you suggested, however there is a bit more to it which I will explain with my own answer (with credit to yours since it led me to solution)